# Compiling apache modules --enable-mods-shared vs --enable-modules

Tags: compiling, apache-httpd

A snippet from the Apache `httpd-2.4` configure document:

```
--enable-mods-shared=MODULE-LIST

Defines a list of modules to be enabled and build as dynamic shared modules. This mean, these module have to be loaded dynamically by using the LoadModule directive.

--enable-mods-static=MODULE-LIST

This option behaves similar to --enable-mods-shared, but will link the given modules statically. This mean, these modules will always be present while running `httpd`. They need not be loaded with LoadModule.

--enable-modules=MODULE-LIST

This option behaves similar to --enable-mods-shared, and will also link the given modules dynamically. The special keyword none disables the build of all modules.
```

Does this mean that if using `--enable-modules`, it will automatically link at run time, without having to use the `LoadModule` directive? What's the benefit of this? I understand the difference between a static and dynamic library, but this just confused me.

Answer (score 1):

Nope, the `--enable-modules` option exist for the purpose of being able to set `--enable-module=none`.  The specific `autoconf` behaviour is in [`acinclude.m4`](https://github.com/apache/httpd/blob/trunk/acinclude.m4).

```
AC_ARG_ENABLE(modules,
APACHE_HELP_STRING(--enable-modules=MODULE-LIST,Space-separated list of modules to enable | "all" | "most" | "few" | "none" | "reallyall"),[
  if test "$enableval" = "none"; then
     module_default=no
     module_selection=none
  else
    for i in $enableval; do
      if test "$i" = "all" -o "$i" = "most" -o "$i" = "few" -o "$i" = "reallyall"
      then
        module_selection=$i
      else
        i=`echo $i | sed 's/-/_/g'`
        eval "enable_$i=shared"
      fi
    done
  fi
])

AC_ARG_ENABLE(mods-shared,
APACHE_HELP_STRING(--enable-mods-shared=MODULE-LIST,Space-separated list of shared modules to enable | "all" | "most" | "few" | "reallyall"),[
  for i in $enableval; do
    if test "$i" = "all" -o "$i" = "most" -o "$i" = "few" -o "$i" = "reallyall"
    then
      module_selection=$i
      module_default=shared
    else
      i=`echo $i | sed 's/-/_/g'`
      eval "enable_$i=shared"
    fi
  done
])
```

`--enable-mods-shared` does not allow a `none` argument.

The only extra difference is that `--enable-modules` does not set `module_default`.  `module_default` is guessed close to the beginning of the script and set to `shared` if possible, or `static` if dynamic shared objects are not supported on the system.

Later, if the module names are set to `most`, `all` or `reallyall`, these modules will be built according to what `module_default` is set to.

Answer (score 0):

Here from the documentation https://httpd.apache.org/docs/trunk/programs/configure.html

```
--enable-modules=MODULE-LIST
    This option behaves like to --enable-mods-shared, and will also link the given modules dynamically. The special keyword none disables the build of all modules.
```

I hope this clarifies that they are linked dynamically.